# Sum of Fibonacci series in ProLog program Execution

Tags: recursion, prolog, fibonacci

I have just started ProLog programming and trying to write sum of Fibonacci series program.

I have one question about this given code.

Can anyone tell me how this gonna work (Execution of Method) because i try it with printing N1,N2 value to figure out what is happening but still can't get it and also can't figured out how F1 and F2 is storing sum of series.

```
fib(0,0).
fib(1,1).
fib(F,N):-
  N > 1,
  N1 is N-1,
  N2 is N-2,
  fib(F1,N1),
  fib(F2,N2),
  F is F1 + F2.
```

Comment: This is a simplistic (very inefficient) recursive definition that simply says that the n-th Fibonacci number is the sum of the (n-1)st and (n-2)nd Fibonacci numbers. It will work but it heavily recomputes prior Fibonacci numbers unnecessarily. You know the definition of the Fibonacci sequence, yes?

Comment: 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8 am i correct?  actually i found this code from stackoverflow. I go with n1=0,n2=1, temp=n1+n2, n1=n2, n2=temp @lurker

Comment: Indeed, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8 are the first 6 Fibonacci sequence numbers. Technically, it starts at 1, 1, although starting at 0, 1 works since the next number in the sequence is then 1.

Comment: I know how to write program of sum of fibonacci. But i want to know how this code execute and how it is giving true answer, can you tell me how this code execute ? @lurker

Comment: As I was saying, the code exactly follows the definition as I described it in my first comment. `fib(F, N)` is true (that is, `F` is the `N`-th Fibonacci number) if each of the following statements holds true. `N1` and `N2` represent the previous two Fibonacci number indices, `F1` and `F2` represent the two previous Fibonacci numbers (computed recursively), and `F is F1 + F2` defines the new Fibonacci number. If you want to see how it executes, use `trace`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The queries for 0 and 1 are pretty straightforward, since you have defined them as facts. If you ask for the 0th number:

```
   ?- fib(X,0).
```

Prolog tries the first rule and successfully matches `0` with the second argument. Then `X` is unified with 0. Since `X` is a variable, unification simply consists of substituting `X` with `0`. This yields the first solution:

```
   ?- fib(X,0).
X = 0 ?
```

If you enter `;` Prolog searches for further solutions:

```
   ?- fib(X,0).
X = 0 ?;
```

The second rule does not match because `1=0` can't be unified. So Prolog tries the third rule. The `N` in the head of the rule is successfully unified with `0`. But the first goal in the body of the rule fails since `0>1` does not hold. So the third rule fails. There are no more rules left to try so Prolog concludes that there are no more solutions:

```
X = 0 ?;
no
```

The query for the 1st number goes almost the same with the only difference that this time around the first rule fails while the second succeeds. Think that one through as an exercise. Now for a more interesting case:

```
   ?- fib(X,2).
```

Prolog tries the first two rules and fails since neither `0=2` nor `1=2` can be unified. Then Prolog tries the third rule and successfully unifies `N=2`. The first goal succeeds since `2>1`. The second goal evaluates `N1=1`. The third goal evaluates `N2=0`. The fourth goal recursively calls

```
fib(F1,1)
```

This succeeds with the second rule of fib/2 (see above), hence the substitution `F1=1`. Back from the recursion Prolog moves on to the fifth goal and recursively calls

```
fib(F2,0)
```

As discussed above this succeeds with the first rule, hence the substitution `F2=0`. Back from the recursion again Prolog moves on to the last goal and evaluates `F=1`. This yields the first solution of the query:

```
   ?- fib(X,2).
X = 1 ?
```

By entering `;` you ask for further solutions:

```
   ?- fib(X,2).
X = 1 ? ;
```

So Prolog backtracks to the fifth goal and tries to find further solutions for it but fails (see above). Then Prolog backtracks to the fourth goal and tries to find further solutions for it but fails. The same goes for goals three, two and one. So Prolog tells you that there are no further solutions:

```
   ?- fib(X,2).
X = 1 ? ;
no
```

If you want to get a feel for this, take a sheet of paper and try the queries for 3 and 4. You can check your results with `trace` as @lurker suggested in the comments.